# AngularJS post request doesn't get server response correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, steroids

I'm developing a hybrid mobile application using AppGyver Steroids and AngularJS. In this mobile application I need to use the RESTful APIs of another project which I've developed; here is an example request I'm sending from the mobile app:

```
var data = {
    'email': $scope.userEmail,
    'password': $scope.userPassword
}

$http.post('http://example.com/api-auth-token/?format=json', data)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data);
        $location.path('/profile');
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // show error details
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Authentication failed. (' + status + ')',
            null,
            'Error',
            'Okay'
        );
    });
```

This request reaches the server perfectly well and a valid response is generated with status code 200... at least that is the case when I check the server logs. The mobile application shows a message box saying 'Authentication failed. (404)' which contradicts with what the server logs are stating.

Edit: I have also developed a native iOS app which uses these APIs and it works without any problems.

Comment: 404 is not authentication failed. 404 is page not found.

Comment: I know. This is a snippet from my sign in function though, so that's why I'm writing that as a message (along with the status code so I can tell why exactly it failed).

Comment: Status is the confusion - is it the status returned by the server or you are returning 404 status code from the authentication api?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. Edited my question. My post data reaches the server, and the server replies with a valid response (status code 200) according to the logs. However my error callback gets called instead of my success callback.

Comment: Sorry, information you have given is not enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Access-Control-Allow-Origin header was missing from responses generated by the server and this was the main culprit.