# AppGyver and AngularJS $http.get fails with status code 0

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, steroids

Recently I have started trying apps with AppGyver and AngularJS. I have added angular resource  (ng-resource) as mentioned at http://academy.appgyver.com/courses/15/lessons/35. I have tried using $http.get to get data from a url which is returning error message as blank and status as 0. Using XMLHttpRequest correctly gets the data but not with $http.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue or point me to a sample app that utilises this behaviour.

Comment: I have just found another question  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729938/angularjs-post-request-doesnt-get-server-response-correctly, this tells about enabling access control allow origin header via web.config. I shall try this today

Comment: Website is already configured for "access control allow origin header" and I still have the issue